# "using" multiple IDisposables from a single function

Tags: c#, pointers

I have a method that returns a `NativeList<>` of structs `AStruct`, where `NativeList<>` is a wrapper over unmanaged memory that implements `IDisposable`. AStruct contains another pointer backed by a `NativeList<float>` also created in the same method, so:

```
private unsafe NativeList<AStruct> GetAStructs()
{
    var floatList = new NativeList<float>();
    floatList.Add(0.0f);

    var list = new NativeList<AStruct>();

    AStruct a1 = new AStruct();
    a1.floats = (float*)floatList.Data;
    list.Add(a1);

    // ...

    return list;
}
```

This is a problem because now `floatList` is not referenced anymore after calling `GetAStructs()`. So I've changed the method signature to include an out parameter.

```
private unsafe NativeList<AStruct> GetAStructs(out IDisposable toDispose)
{
    // ...

    toDispose = floatList;
    return list;
}
```

And I'm calling it like this

```
using (NativeList<AStruct> disposableList = GetAStructs(out IDisposable toDispose))
using (toDispose)
{
    callNativeFunction((AStruct*)disposableList.Data);
}
```

Will this work as intended? Is there a way to do this without exposing an implementation detail to the calling method?

Comment: If `NativeList<>` already implements `IDisposable`, why not just let it handle disposing of the resource?

Comment: If you don't want to expose this kind of implementation detail, you need to let `NativeList<AStruct>` take ownership of the `NativeList<float>` (i.e., NativeList<AStruct> will keep a private reference to the NativeList<float> it depends on and will have to take care of disposing it. That means you will have to change the implementation of NativeList<T> to support this.

Comment: I don't want `floatList` to be disposed before the native function is called, and the first `NativeList<>` of `AStruct`s only contains a pointer to the data. I don't have access to the implementation of `NativeList<>`

Comment: Okay, then don't let GetAStructs return a NativeList. Create a IDisposable class that will hold both NativeLists (and takes care of their disposal) and this should be the return type for GetAStructs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll admit I don't know much about NativeArray, but in cases like this you can often get the functionality you need by creating a subclass of the class you're working with.

In this case, I'd suggest you create a subclass of `NativeList` that includes a callback for disposal. Pass it a function that will do the work that you were previously asking the caller to do.

Example subclass:

```
class MyNativeList<T> : NativeList<T>
{
    protected readonly Action _callAfterDisposal;

    public MyNativeList(Action callAfterDisposal) : base()
    {
        _callAfterDisposal= callAfterDisposal;
    }

    public override Dispose()
    {
        base.Dispose();
        _callAfterDisposal();
    }
}
```

Setting up the callback:

```
private unsafe NativeList<AStruct> GetAStructs()
{
    var floatList = new NativeList<float>();
    floatList.Add(0.0f);

    //here we construct the MyNativeList and pass it an action to execute when it is disposed
    var list = new MyNativeList<AStruct>( () => {
        callNativeFunction((AStruct*)floatList.Data);
        floatList.Dispose();
    });

    AStruct a1 = new AStruct();
    a1.floats = (float*)floatList.Data;
    list.Add(a1);

    // ...

    return list;
}
```

When you do this, the native list of floats is captured in a closed variable. Your caller just needs to dispose of the list per normal, and when the callback is made, the native list of floats gets disposed as well.

```
using ( var disposableList = GetAStructs() ) 
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Notice that `GetAStructs()` still returns a reference to a `NativeList<T>` (not a `MyNativeList<>`) so the implementation details do not leak to the caller unless they go out of their way to cast the result.